# В каком предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка ?

Tags: пунктуация

1) В лесу было тихо, и среди этого безмолвия иногда раздавался голос кукушки.
2) Кое-где по стенам сочилась вода, и слегка блестели известковые налёты.
3) Она глядит, и сердце её бьётся чаще и сильней.
4) Упали две-три крупные капли дождя, и вдруг блеснула молния.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором. "Кое-где по стенам" - общее обстоятельство для двух грамматических основ, поэтому запятая не нужна.